# Handling many comboboxes and textboxes

Tags: vba, excel

I've designed a userform in Excel and it has many comboboxes and textbox inputs, once the user is done it puts ticks in appropriate columns depending on the ComboBox selection and also writes the value of the TextBox to the sheet.

At the moment I feel as though the sub could be refined but am unsure how to proceed as the ComboBoxes are not regular in the number of options each have.

I was thinking of using `.listindex` in place of the offset number. Any thoughts on proceeding with that?

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

If Projects.EnableMisc = False And Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = "New" Then      'sets the save data for misc if it's not turned, so that if it is enabled it has some settings and the checkboxes are not set to triple state.
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveMisc1").Column).Value = 0
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveMisc2").Column).Value = 0
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveXMisc1").Column).Value = False
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveXMisc2").Column).Value = False
End If


Dim RangeName As String
Dim dblTBox As Double

Range(ActiveCell, Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("CostBuilding").Column)).ClearContents    'clears contents incase changes are made, this prevents multiple ticks showing in a single section

'writes the project name into the first column
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1).Value = Me.TextBoxName

'writes the ticks to the sheet
RangeName = "ProjFeasibility"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxFeasibility.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxFeasibility.Value
    Case "Yes"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjConcept"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxConcept.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 4).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxConcept.Value
    Case "Review"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjDetail"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxDetail.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 4).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxDetail.Value
    Case "Review"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjLandscape"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxLandscape.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxLandscape.Value
    Case "Parks Team"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Preliminary"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Detail"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjLighting"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxLighting.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxLighting.Value
    Case "Minor"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Streets"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Oval"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjRSA"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxRSA.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxRSA.Value
    Case "Yes"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjSurvey"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxSurvey.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxSurvey.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjGeotech"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxGeotech.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxGeotech.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjService"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxService.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxService.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjVegetation"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxVegetation.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxVegetation.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjOffset"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxOffset.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxOffset.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjCHMP"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxCHMP.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxCHMP.Value
    Case "Due Diligence"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Full"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjPlanning"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxPlanning.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxPlanning.Value
    Case "Yes"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

RangeName = "ProjBuilding"
dblTBox = Me.TextBoxBuilding.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = dblTBox

Select Case Me.ComboBoxBuilding.Value
    Case "Yes"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select

'autofills the sum formulas
Range("ProjAutoFill").AutoFill Destination:=Range("ProjAutoFill:LRowFill")

'writes the current values of options to sheet so that it can be accessed by the EditUserForm sub so that the form "remembers" what was selected
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("CanEdit").Column).Value = "Y"
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveFeasibility").Column).Value = ComboBoxFeasibility.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveConcept").Column).Value = ComboBoxConcept.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveDetail").Column).Value = ComboBoxDetail.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveLandscape").Column).Value = ComboBoxLandscape.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveLighting").Column).Value = ComboBoxLighting.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveRSA").Column).Value = ComboBoxRSA.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveSurvey").Column).Value = ComboBoxSurvey.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveGeoTech").Column).Value = ComboBoxGeotech.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveService").Column).Value = ComboBoxService.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveVegetation").Column).Value = ComboBoxVegetation.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveOffset").Column).Value = ComboBoxOffset.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveCHMP").Column).Value = ComboBoxCHMP.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SavePlanning").Column).Value = ComboBoxPlanning.ListIndex
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveBuilding").Column).Value = ComboBoxBuilding.ListIndex

Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveXDetail").Column).Value = CheckBoxDetail.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveXLandscape").Column).Value = CheckBoxLandscape.Value
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range("SaveXSurvey").Column).Value = CheckBoxSurvey.Value

'hides the last row
Range("LRow").EntireRow.Hidden = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Unload Me

If Projects.EnableMisc.Value = True Then
    MiscInsert.Show
Else
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like using `ListIndex` could cut down your code considerably, however this may reduce the readability of your code, and you may need to reorder the options in the `ComboBox` or where the data is saved.

---

```
Select Case Me.ComboBoxOffset.Value
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select
```

By using `ListIndex` you could cut this function down to:

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, ComboBoxOffset.ListIndex).Value = "ü"
```

`ListIndex` returns the index number of the option selected, in this case:

> 0 - Large
>
> 1 - Medium
>
> 2 - Small
>
> (This assumes that the options are ordered in this way in your ComboBox)

Note how the index begins at 0 like `Arrays`, this is useful in your case as your first option "Large" requires no `Offset`. By using `ListIndex` within `Offset` the option "Large" is effectively `Offset(0, 0)`, in other words no offset is made, and so you don't need to write an `If` statement to handle the first option exclusively.

---

```
Select Case Me.ComboBoxConcept.Value
    Case "Review"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Value = "ü"
    Case "Large"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 1).Value = "ü"
    Case "Medium"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 2).Value = "ü"
    Case "Small"
        Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, 3).Value = "ü"
    Case Else
End Select
```

So how could we use `ListIndex` to reduce this one? Well...

```
Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, ComboBoxConcept.ListIndex).Value = "ü"
```

It's the same one line of code, only the name of the `ComboBox` has been changed, pretty simple stuff.

---

**Potential issue**

Something to note with `ListIndex` is that if no option has been selected in the ComboBox, `ListIndex` will return a value of -1. This is an issue in your case as the offset will be (0, -1), meaning it will write in a column it shouldn't.

The easiest way to get around this is to check that an option has been selected before changing any cell values:

```
If ComboBoxOffset.ListIndex <> -1 then
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, ComboBoxOffset.ListIndex).Value = "ü"
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd redesign the code to make it more clear and maintainable:

### 1. use dictionary to store selection options and corresponding values

```
    With ConceptDictionary
        .Add "Review", 0
        .Add "Large", 1
        .Add "Medium", 2
        .Add "Small", 3
    End With
```

This way you can easily compose your range reference:

`Cells(ActiveCell.Row, Range(RangeName).Column).Offset(0, ConceptDictionary.Item(Me.ComboBoxConcept.Value)).Value = "ü"`

This might seem complicated, but it has it's advantages:

- you can keep all the constant values together, and review them if necessary
- no need to adapt order in combobox to order in sheet

### 2. Keep related data together

Create a custom type where you can collect related ranges and objects:

```
Public Type RelatedData
    DataRange As Range
    TitleControl As Object
    SelectionControl As Object
    SelectionOptions As Dictionary
End Type

Public DataToProcess() As RelatedData
```

This way you can create a sub which loads the information:

```
Sub LoadData()
    ReDim DataToProcess(1 To 10) ' adapt to the size of your data

    With DataToProcess(1)
        Set .DataRange = Range("ProjConcept")
        Set .TitleControl = Me.TextBoxConcept.Value
        Set .SelectionOptions = New Dictionary
        With .SelectionOptions
            .Add "Review", 0
            .Add "Large", 1
            .Add "Medium", 2
            .Add "Small", 3
        End With
    End With

    With DataToProcess(2)
        ' repeat for all data...
    End With
End Sub
```

So you've everything together in a condensed way, just need to refresh if anything is changed..

### 3. loop through your custom type

```
Sub FillData()
    Dim i As Integer

    For i = LBound(DataToProcess) To UBound(DataToProcess)
        With DataToProcess(i)
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, .DataRange.Column).Offset(0, _
                4).Value = .TitleControl.Value
            Cells(ActiveCell.Row, .DataRange.Column).Offset(0, _
                .SelectionOptions.Item(.SelectionControl.Value)).Value = "ü"
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

And really a small sub doing the job.

Comment: I don't have much experience with dictionaries, is it possible to populate a ComBobox using a dictionary? I wasn't able to find any examples online but would something like `ComboboxConcept.add ConceptDictionary(i)` and then loop LBound to UBound work, or is it possible to add the whole dictionary at once?


and would it be possible to `set .selectionoptions = ConceptDictionary`?


I think that using the same dictionary to assign values to everything would increase maintainability and reduce errors, thoughts?